# define you own Meta class options

Tags: django, django-models

the following link list all possible metadata options for a Django model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options. Does Django provide a framework to extend the list by defining my own metadata options? e.g., I want to add a custom option secured = True to mask the value of some fields. If so, how?

Comment: This does not look like something for a model (which is focused on storing/retrieving/aggregating/...) the data. What you are looking for is more the responsibility of a form *field*.

Comment: I figured it out: Django provides the _meta API which can be used for this purpose